# Installing FreeRDP using chocolatey gives me no executable to run?

Tags: chocolatey, choco

I did a `choco install freerdp` and tried looking for the exe in program files etc

There's a folder in the User directory but doesn't contain anything useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the installation of the freerdp package, Chocolatey tried to help you understand where the underlying application was being installed.

[image]

In the case of this package, it is a portable application, so the application doesn't have an entry within add/remove programs.  The maintainer of this package has chosen to extract the zip file for the application directly into the packages tools folder, i.e.

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\freerdp\tools
```

A shim exe has also been created though, which should mean you should be able to run `wfreerdp` directly from the command line.

For future packages, you can look at the [files](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/freerdp#files) contained within the package to get an understanding of how the underlying application is going to be installed.

Comment: Hi, thank you. The wfreerdp.exe doesn't really do anything (either from the commandline or double clicking in explorer) but your answer is correct.